# Issue when trying to read multiplte entity resultsets from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

We using EF5.0 and code-first approach with MS SQL Server
I have read an article 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

and decided to try the same approach over our database

however, suppose that my stores procedure contains a query like this

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[MyEntities] as MyEntity
    where ID = @ID
```

and code in C# is

```
var entities = Context.ObjectContext.Translate<MyEntity>(reader, "MyEntity", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

I am getting at this point

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The EntitySet name 'MyDbContext.MyEntity'
>   could not be found.

So, obviously it adds some context name as a prefix to the EntitySet name and instead of MyEntity is looking for MyDbContext.MyEntity in the result set.

What causes this behaviour and if there is any workaroud (because in example I referenced above it looks quite streightforward and simple and no specific manipulations is needed, except call db.Database.Initialize(force: false); (which I do in my code as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I find an answer myself
If seems that table aliases not working and code-first mapping configurations between the entity classes and table name also not taken into account when you call Translate

So I need to specify original table name (MyEntities) instead of MyEntity in this line of code

```
var entities = Context.ObjectContext.Translate<MyEntity>(reader, "MyEntities", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the same exception, even I don't use aliases in my select functions.
I ended up by using the overloaded method of **Translate** by passing only the reader. I already know the order of the select functions so I do not need to pass the **EntitySet** name.

```
var entities_1 = Context.ObjectContext.Translate<MyEntity_1>(reader);
reader.NextResult();
var entities_2 = Context.ObjectContext.Translate<MyEntity_2>(reader);
```